# "mount" on 2.3.4 is Behaving Oddly

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, mount, busybox

I'm on Nexus S, 2.3.4, stock and rooted. BusyBox is v1.18.4 (2011-03-20 15:16:04 CDT). When I try to remount *ANYTHING* it just

```
$ mount -o remount,rw /system
Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory
```

Any ideas how to fix that? Is it a BusyBox issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not specifying the device to mount, only the directory so it is telling you that you are missing one of the required parameters.

I believe that the `busybox mount` will let you get away with not supplying the device, if it can figure out the device to mount, but the "stock" `mount` requires that you supply both the directory and the device.

you would have to do the following:

`# mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/mtdblock4 /system`

or you could try the `busybox mount`

`# busybox mount -o remount,rw /system`

but you should always supply the device to mount, so there is no confusion or issue with mounting the wrong device.

Comment: busybox mount -o remount,rw /system did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You may have root, but that is not a root shell (as evidenced by the `$` prompt). You need to use `su` to switch to root before you can use `mount`. Since the default target is the root UID, you can simply enter `su` and it should properly switch to root (a `#` prompt). I think the reason it's failing is simply because you're running it as an underprivileged user.

Comment: Same with # mount -o remount,rw /system

Comment: @bot47: Strangely that works for me, but I suppose the other test would be to specify a device. E.g. something like `mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/mtdblock4 /system` where `/dev/block/mtdblock4` is the partition where `/system` lives (I think Nexus S is `mtdblock3` but you can check with just `mount` by itself).